# How to set Crystal Reports data source to a class that's outside of this project?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I’m trying to use Crystal Reports’s Database Expert dialogue - Project Data/.Net Objects, to connect to a C# public class – iEnumerable as its datasource. However when I expand the "Project Data" tree it seems that the list of classes that are available to choose from are only those that are part of the same project that the report belongs to. While this public class is accessible from other projects in this solution and all reports reside in another project of the same solution, ".Net Objects" only shows the list of classes where the Crystal Report resides. How do I find and set it to other classes in another project?

I’m using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2015, CR v13.0.19.2312.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the first project then add its dll file as a new reference in the other one